# Javascript sort array by "groups" and maintain order

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, sorting

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
[
{
    "name": "Item1",
    "section": "section1",
    "total": 3,
}, {
    "name": "Item1",
    "section": "section2",
    "total": 4,
}{
    "name": "Item1",
    "section": "section3",
    "total": 7,
}, {
    "name": "Item2",
    "section": "section1",
    "total": 1,
}, {
    "name": "Item2",
    "section": "section2",
    "total": 2,
}, {
    "name": "Item2",
    "section": "section3",
    "total": 3,
    }
]
```

I need to sort the array by only the total value in the section 3 item, but maintain the order (section1, section2, then section 3) per name. So for this example Item2 should move all 3 of it's rows above Item1. I've tried sorting by multiple items, but that doesn't maintain the ordering that I need. Should I just get the smallest/biggest, grab the related items and put them into a new array and repeat or is there a more logical way to accomplish this?

I'm also using angular and primeng grid if there's something I can leverage in there.

Comment: you need a stable sort, the build in is not stable IIRC.

Comment: what you mean by *I've tried sorting by multiple items,*? this doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: do you have always three items in a group? please add the wanted result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a map using the `name` as the key and the `total` as the value for items where `section` equals `section3`. You can then sort using the map.

This will sort all items by the value of the `total` in `section3`, and preserve the original sort order where the sort value matches.

```js
const map = new Map<string, number>(this.data
  .filter(x => x.section === 'section3')
  .map(x => [ x.name, x.total ]));

this.sorted = this.data.slice()
  .sort((a, b) => map.get(a.name) - map.get(b.name));
```

This does rely on the data being structured and ordered as your have specified in your question.

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fsswdq

Answer (score 2):

**Priority sort**

```js
const data = [{"name":"Item1","section":"section1","total":3},{"name":"Item1","section":"section2","total":4},{"name":"Item1","section":"section3","total":7},{"name":"Item2","section":"section1","total":1},{"name":"Item2","section":"section2","total":2},{"name":"Item2","section":"section3","total":3}];
console.log(
  data.sort((a, b) => {
    const diff = a.total - b.total;
    if (diff) return diff;
    return b.section.localeCompare(a.section);
  })
);
```

```css
.as-console-row {color: blue!important}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could

- collect all object of the same group and get the total for sorting,
- sort by the groups `total` value,
- get a flat array of all objects.

```js
const
    data = [{ name: "Item1", section: "section1", total: 3 }, { name: "Item1", section: "section2", total: 4 }, { name: "Item1", section: "section3", total: 7 }, { name: "Item2", section: "section1", total: 1 }, { name: "Item2", section: "section2", total: 2 }, { name: "Item2", section: "section3", total: 3 }],
    result = Object
        .values(data.reduce((r, o) => {
            r[o.name] = r[o.name] || { payload: [] };
            r[o.name].payload.push(o);
            if (o.section === 'section3') r[o.name].total = o.total;
            return r;
        }, {}))
        .sort(({ total: a }, { total: b }) => a - b)
        .flatMap(({ payload }) => payload);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = [
{
    "name": "Item1",
    "section": "section1",
    "total": 3,
}, {
    "name": "Item1",
    "section": "section2",
    "total": 4,
},{
    "name": "Item1",
    "section": "section3",
    "total": 7,
}, {
    "name": "Item2",
    "section": "section1",
    "total": 1,
}, {
    "name": "Item2",
    "section": "section2",
    "total": 2,
}, {
    "name": "Item2",
    "section": "section3",
    "total": 3,
    }
];

array = array.sort((o1, o2)=>{

if(o1.section === o2.section && o1.section === 'section3') {
   return o1.total - o2.total;
} else {
  return o1.section === 'section3' ? 1 : -1;
}
});

console.log(array);
```

Here's the output

```
[
  {
    "name": "Item1",
    "section": "section1",
    "total": 3
  },
  {
    "name": "Item1",
    "section": "section2",
    "total": 4
  },
  {
    "name": "Item2",
    "section": "section1",
    "total": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "Item2",
    "section": "section2",
    "total": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "Item2",
    "section": "section3",
    "total": 3
  },
  {
    "name": "Item1",
    "section": "section3",
    "total": 7
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to "Group" the data set by `name` and then do the sorting by `total`.

```js
let items = [{
  "name": "Item1",
  "section": "section1",
  "total": 3,
}, {
  "name": "Item1",
  "section": "section2",
  "total": 4,
}, {
  "name": "Item1",
  "section": "section3",
  "total": 7,
}, {
  "name": "Item2",
  "section": "section1",
  "total": 1,
}, {
  "name": "Item2",
  "section": "section2",
  "total": 2,
}, {
  "name": "Item2",
  "section": "section3",
  "total": 3,
}];

let groups = {};

for (let item of items) {
  if (!groups[item.name]) {
    groups[item.name] = {
      data: []
    };
  }

  // Grouping by `name`
  groups[item.name].data.push(item);

  // Store the `total`
  if (item.section == "section3") {
    groups[item.name].key = item.total;
  }
}

// sort the groups, this will maintain the order of sections (1,2 and 3) in each group
let sortedGroups = Object.values(groups).sort((a, b) => {
  return a.key - b.key; // ascending
});

// then flatten the groups
let flatten = [].concat(...sortedGroups.map(x => x.data));

console.log(flatten);
```